# Access Denied after Change Form Authentication To Disable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got Access denied if I change Form Authentication To Disable while am in Owner Group of Sharepoint.

and when I put enable it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the web.config contains the appropriate configuration information when compared to the web applications settings.
Check the web application settings:

Navigate to Central Administration - Application Management - Manage web applications.
Select the web application in question
Click on the 'Authentication Providers' link from the ribbon
Choose the appropriate zone for the web application
The dialog box will display the type of membership provider (Windows or Claims-Based Authentication).
Record the name of membership provider for the specific zone in the 'Authentication Provider' dialog box.
Locate the web.config file for the web application:
Typically the web.config file is stored at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\Port_Number
Verify the following section in the web.config file

    
      
   

If the membership provider name is Windows, then authentication mode should be set to "Windows".
If the membership provider is Claims-based authentication, then the authentication mode should be set to "Forms".
In nutshell, authentication setting in IIS and WebApplication should match.

[Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2655719/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your user badge shows detail about you like your name and reputation. Don't need to include it in the answer :)